# Bidirectional file sync in ubuntu

Tags: synchronization

I need to multiple file, folder sync in two ubuntu servers. 

A server syncs to B.
B server syncs to A.

**rsync**: sync one way
**unison**: sync only one folder.

There is any other two way(bidirectional) file sync tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unison can do more than one folder.
Perhaps you are thinking of their "root folders" as the only way to control what gets backed up, but you also have paths.

If anything the only problem (if it can be considered that) is that it seems unison is no longer updated.

Additionaly the first sync on unison between two roots can be a very lengthy process.